# Using a table inside a figure tag, otherwise changing table caption to figure

Tags: tables, floats, formatting

I've used a table of figures in order to format their presentation and order.
But essentially the whole thing is a figure, so I want it now to get "Figure 5" as a caption. To do that I guess I have to put the entire table inside a figure.

This is what I'm doing, but all that happens is that the caption shows up, but the table isn't there, and there is an error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par 
>    mode.

The code is as follows:

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\caption{Confusion matrices: Single 29-class model}
\label{Figure 5}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c X c }
\textbf{GentleBoost} & & \textbf{Baseline} \\ \noalign{\smallskip}\\ 
\includegraphics[width=7.25cm]{singlematrix_g1} & & \includegraphics[width=7.25cm]{singlematrix_b1} \\ \noalign{\smallskip}\\ 
\includegraphics[width=7.25cm]{singlematrix_g2} & & \includegraphics[width=7.25cm]{singlematrix_b2} \\ \noalign{\smallskip}\\ 
\includegraphics[width=7.25cm]{singlematrix_g3} & & \includegraphics[width=7.25cm]{singlematrix_b3} \\ \noalign{\smallskip}\\ 
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{figure*}
```

However, my only issue is to have it show up as a figure and not table. If it's possible to change the caption from Table to Figure easily - then I'd prefer that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to reduce the image size, but there you are:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c X c }
            \textbf{GentleBoost} & & \textbf{Baseline} \\ \noalign{\bigskip} 
            \includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{singlematrix_g1} & & \includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{singlematrix_b1} \\ \noalign{\bigskip}
            \includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{singlematrix_g2} & & \includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{singlematrix_b2} \\ \noalign{\bigskip} 
            \includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{singlematrix_g3} & & \includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{singlematrix_b3} \\ \noalign{\bigskip} 
        \end{tabularx}
    \captionof{figure}{Confusion matrices: Single 29-class model}\label{Figure 5}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This has the disadvantage of not being guaranteed to be in the correct order with respect to other figures

Comment: @user961627 I just corrected your error. But if your final result will stay like it is here (empty middle column) I would strongly recommend David's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a`figure` environment, but rather `\captionof`, defined in the `caption` package. Here is a fragment of code:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\captionof{figure}{Confusion matrices: Single 29-class model}
\label{Figure 5}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c X c }
\textbf{GentleBoost} & & \textbf{Baseline} \\ \noalign{\smallskip}\\
\includegraphics[width=7.25cm]{singlematrix_g1} & & \includegraphics[width=7.25cm]{singlematrix_b1} \\ \noalign{\smallskip}\\
\includegraphics[width=7.25cm]{singlematrix_g2} & & \includegraphics[width=7.25cm]{singlematrix_b2} \\ \noalign{\smallskip}\\
\includegraphics[width=7.25cm]{singlematrix_g3} & & \includegraphics[width=7.25cm]{singlematrix_b3} \\ \noalign{\smallskip}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: This has the disadvantage of not being guaranteed to be in the correct order with respect to other figures

Comment: @David Carlisle: You're right. Anyway, as far as I know, LaTeX makes no semantic analysis to detect whether the contents of a figure environment is indeed a figure. So a simple figure would do — but you've already answered that, and added some useful comments…

Answer (score 1):

Just use `figure` not `table`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c X c }
            \textbf{GentleBoost} & & \textbf{Baseline} \\ \noalign{\bigskip} 
            \includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{singlematrix_g1} & & \includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{singlematrix_b1} \\ \noalign{\bigskip}
            \includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{singlematrix_g2} & & \includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{singlematrix_b2} \\ \noalign{\bigskip} 
            \includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{singlematrix_g3} & & \includegraphics[width=1.25cm]{singlematrix_b3} \\ \noalign{\bigskip} 
        \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Confusion matrices: Single 29-class model}\label{Figure 5}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But don't use `tabularx` for this it is slow and painful and since the X column is empty not doing anything very useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}

            \makebox[5.25cm]{\textbf{GentleBoost}}\hfill \makebox[5.25cm]{\textbf{Baseline} }

\bigskip


            \includegraphics[width=5.25cm]{singlematrix_g1}\hfill\includegraphics[width=5.25cm]{singlematrix_b1}

\bigskip

            \includegraphics[width=5.25cm]{singlematrix_g2}\hfill\includegraphics[width=5.25cm]{singlematrix_b2}

\bigskip
            \includegraphics[width=5.25cm]{singlematrix_g3}\hfill\includegraphics[width=5.25cm]{singlematrix_b3}

\bigskip

    \caption{Confusion matrices: Single 29-class model}\label{Figure 5}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The reason for the X column was that the images are actually pretty big and fat, they take up most of the page and so the empty column in the middle ends up just being a narrow space.

Comment: @user961627 but `\hfill` is a _space_ that stretches for exactly that reason and takes exactly one cycle of TeX's inner loop to digest that token.  I wrote `tabularx` and I have no idea how many thousands of cycles of the inner loop it takes to make `tabularx` achieve the same thing with an empty column.